# Perspective CSS out of DIV

Tags: html, css, perspective

I'm rewriting the map engine of my `Pokémon` game, but I've got a problem. 
With using of perspective (for 3D view), the content of the DIV go out of the Map DIV container.

Perspective Problem Image
[image: Perspective Problem Image]

Normal view with borders
[image: Normal view with borders]

Demo : http://www.pokedev.in/test.html

I would like to know if it's possible to fix that by a way (force CSS to stay in DIV ?) and the solution to fix if it exist.

Thanks, 
Loris

(sorry, i'm French, my english is not the very best).

Comment: both images are the same?

Comment: Yes http://i.imgur.com/xmZ3sZQ.png this will be better

Comment: Perhaps set `max-width: 100%` on the div content?

Comment: Didn't change anything. I've put an online demo : http://www.pokedev.in/test.html

Comment: Your demo page doesn't work

Comment: The perspective works no ? I've disable movement for this version but normaly perspective is loading

Comment: @PokExp try setting the height of the map a bit smaller then the div it should look like it's inside of the containing div, but you can't really force it into the div if you play with the z access.

Comment: Aw :/ I will test with smaller div but it will be different, but if it's the solution I will try ^^. Thanks

Comment: Well, with this Css, you will need the top div to be smaller or set the perspective to a much bigger value, this will make the 3d effect look less intense though.

Comment: @PokExp did it work?